# Why the loop does not run properly

Tags: python, windows

I do not understand why the loop does not run my Python script.

```
import gtk, sys
from ctypes import *

PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX = 0x3
PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE = 0x4
PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE = 0x2
PIPE_WAIT = 0
PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES = 255
BUFSIZE = 9600
NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT = 0
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = -1
ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED = 535

MESSAGE = "Default answer from server\0"
szPipename = "\\\\.\\pipe\\mynamedpipe"

def ReadWrite_ClientPipe_Thread(hPipe):
    chBuf = create_string_buffer(BUFSIZE)
    cbRead = c_ulong(0)
    while True:
        fSuccess = windll.kernel32.ReadFile(hPipe, chBuf, BUFSIZE, byref(cbRead), None)
        if ((fSuccess ==1) or (cbRead.value != 0)):
            messageArd = chBuf.value
            cbWritten = c_ulong(0)
            fSuccess = windll.kernel32.WriteFile(hPipe,c_char_p(MESSAGE), len(MESSAGE), byref(cbWritten), None )
    windll.kernel32.FlushFileBuffers(hPipe)
    windll.kernel32.DisconnectNamedPipe(hPipe)
    windll.kernel32.CloseHandle(hPipe)
    return 0

def main(): 
    THREADFUNC = CFUNCTYPE(c_int, c_int)
    thread_func = THREADFUNC(ReadWrite_ClientPipe_Thread)
    while True:
        print "Print test" #This should be repeated
        hPipe = windll.kernel32.CreateNamedPipeA(szPipename,PIPE_ACCESS_DUPLEX,PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE | PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE | PIPE_WAIT,PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,BUFSIZE, BUFSIZE,NMPWAIT_USE_DEFAULT_WAIT,None)
        fConnected = windll.kernel32.ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, None)
        if ((fConnected == 0) and (windll.kernel32.GetLastError() == ERROR_PIPE_CONNECTED)):
            fConnected = 1

        if (fConnected == 1):
            dwThreadId = c_ulong(0)
            hThread = windll.kernel32.CreateThread(None, 0,thread_func, hPipe, 0, byref(dwThreadId))

    gtk.main() 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    main()
```

This should be repeated:

```
 print "Print test"
```

If I change def Main or remove Named Pipe script, the loop will run properly.

```
def main(): 
    while True:
        print "Print test" #This should be repeated
    gtk.main()
```

Can someone help me solve this issue? Thank You

Comment: can you tell us what output/error messages you are getting?

Comment: trying putting a debugger on that and see where it goes.

Comment: there is no error. The loop only run once, and only 1 times print "Print Test". Its should be looping forever.

Comment: I guess it doesn't run forever because something returns False in the way, put print "test bla" after every command in the main script and find out where it is exiting

Comment: You have a while loop with no exit criteria, so that makes the 'gtk.main()' call after it unreachable. Other than that - you say it only runs once. Does it break out of the loop or get stuck in there? Stepping through it in a debugger should be enough to tell you where things go wrong.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I have found the problem.
The loop stopped at the :

   " fConnected = windll.kernel32.ConnectNamedPipe(hPipe, None) "

This is to stop the loop. How can it stop the loop, can someone explain to me? I don't know what it means

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem.

Looping does not work because there are two loops that run concurrently, the solution with multithreading. To run two loops at the same